# Do I need to retopo ALL areas of my mesh?

Tags: texturing, baking, normal-map

Trying to retopo my first character model. In hindsight, I might have layered things differently if I knew I'd end up here. But adding retopology to some areas of the mesh, like the inside of the hood and around the neck are too difficult to get the right angle. If I left some parts the way they are, would it be an issue later? Should I still be able to texture later on?
[image]

Comment: yes you can modify it whenever you want then relaunch a Render, etc...

Comment: So if I was never going to deform that part of the mesh anyway, I don't need to retopologize it? What if I'm animating?

Comment: I'l not sure to understand, you can animate all the way you want and later you can bring all the modifications you want to your mesh, you may need to bring some weight paint modification though, to make sure that the vertices you've added are controlled by the right bone etc...

Comment: I'm not sure if you got my original question. I'm not asking about modifications. I'm asking, if I don't retopologize the inside of the hood for example, would it affect anything later on like texturing, animating, rendering times?

Comment: rendering time I don't think so (you should test with an on and off Mask modifier on this zone) but of course it will affect the lightness of your mesh when you manipulate it in the 3D view.